# How to sort list of dicts by dict value in pre-defined format?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I've got a list of dicts which describe certain classes in a school of which some are still taught, some are not anymore, and some are going to be taught in the future:

```
[
    {'status': 'DEACTIVE', 'name': 'Music'},
    {'status': 'DEACTIVE', 'name': 'Juggling'},
    {'status': 'ACTIVE', 'name': 'Chess'},
    {'status': 'ACTIVE', 'name': 'Dutch Language'},
    {'status': 'COMING', 'name': 'Python'},
    {'status': 'COMING', 'name': 'Drinking coffee like a pro'},
]
```

I now want to order this list so that the `ACTIVE` are first, then the `DEACTIVE`, and finally the `COMING`. I found solutions such as this:

```
sorted(a, key=dict.values, reverse=True)
```

but that only orders it by alphabet where I want to sort it in a custom way. Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: You will need to write your own `key` function, that takes a dictionary and returns e.g. an ordinal for the status. Also, note that that should probably be *"INACTIVE"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Alright, so a key function that returns an ordinal. Any idea how I can do that? I'm kinda in the dark here on how to handle this.

Comment: You have 2.5k rep; you should know by now that *this isn't a code-writing service*. Read the documentation on `sorted`, which explains what form the function should take and links to a how-to, and *try to implement it yourself*. If you get stuck, you can then return with a [mcve] and specific issue.

Comment: seems like you should have a dict of lists, where the dict keys are active, inactive, and coming, and the values for each of those keys are a list of class names which have that status...

Comment: @jonrsharpe - You're right, I know SO is not a code-writing service. I thought of looping of them, separating them in separate lists, and then combining these lists together again, but that just didn't seem very Pythonic. I checked out the docs on sorted, but even after that I had no idea how to do this. Excuse me if my question came across as an `I'm too lazy to do this myself`-question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using dictionary with weight of all statuses:

```
STATUS_RANK = {"ACTIVE": 1, "DEACTIVE": 2, "COMING": 3}

courses.sort(key=lambda x: STATUS_RANK[x['status']])
```

Answer (score 0):

i just made a method to handle that called it order_my_list() as you see below:
all you need is just to pass your list as a parameter!

```
 def order_my_list(lst):
     ordered = []
     loop = 0
     finished_flag = 0
     while finished_flag == 0:
         for x in range(0,len(lst)):
             if loop == 0:
                 if lst[x]['status'] == 'ACTIVE':
                     ordered.append(lst[x])
             if loop == 1:
                 if lst[x]['status'] == 'DEACTIVE':
                     ordered.append(lst[x])
             if loop == 2:
                 if lst[x]['status'] == 'COMING':
                     ordered.append(lst[x])
             if loop == 3:
                 finished_flag = 1

         loop += 1
     return ordered
```

Im sure there is better/faster ways to do it but thats how i would solve it as my python knowledge isnt that great :p ...